# Windows changes the time by one minute regularly, how to get around it?

Tags: windows, delphi, real-time-clock

My windows application developed in Delphi works 7 days a week on a PC that is not connected to the Internet.I developed it to receive the WM_TIMECHANGE message. I notice that I receive this message regularly, at a frequency that seems to depend on the PCs but always with the same offset: 1 minute.

My explanation would be that Windows maintains a software clock that would shift over time and would update itself when the shift reaches one minute, at least that's what I conclude.
Note that this PC is not connected to the Internet and is not on a network.

In the event manager, I can find this information in the System item (source=Kernel-General) with the following message:
*System time changed from 2023-02-08T21:38:00,887702300Z to 2023-02-08T21:39:01.50000000Z.
Reason for change: System time synchronized with the hardware clock.
Procedure: "" (PID4)*

This phenomenon that sometimes happens once every 2/3 months, and sometimes every week.
This is a big problem for me because I store data as it happens and I time it.

I am considering several solutions but I can't figure out how to implement them, I need help:

- read directly the time in the RTC component (Real time clock: component on the motherboard)
- or prevent windows to read back the time from the RTC
- or force Windows to synchronize with the RTC at specific times only (so on demand)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why don't use Delphi function Now() which returns the current date and time from the system ? That is from the real time clock maintained up to date by connecting to a time server (unless you disabled that windows feature).

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, but with using software, like Windows. You should have considered [searching the internet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/367619/system-time-synchronized-with-the-hardware-clock) or [asking on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/862899/650342).

Comment: I actually use the now() instruction which returns the time of the OS but not of the RTC.I have already done a lot of research on the Internet. I give Delphi as a reference to document my problem. And if I can get an example in Delphi to, for example, inhibit the synchronization of Windows with the hardware clock, I would be very interested. 
I remind that the PC is not connected to the Internet or to a network.


Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: IMO, this is a question for the [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) site. Anyway, check Windows messages `GetSystemTimeAdjustment` and `SetSystemTimeAdjustment` to take control of when the system attempts to synchronize with external time services. As you are not connected to the net, you will have to accept that the RTC drifts a way from reality. Or you may choose to have your own time server that is connected to the internet and handles time changes internally to your other machine(s) that are not.

Comment: Check CMOS batter on your computers motherboard. The fact that windows needs to adjust time by a whole minute might indicate almost empty CMOS battery. Yes on most computers internal clock is being powered by CMOS battery even when computer is turned on so it will eventually drain. And first indicator of low charge of CMOS battery is often an internal clock not running at proper speed.

Comment: All you guys should really follow links being posted: Not having a Time Server means Windows uses the [Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) to do that overly often. Yes, nowaday's versions (or even Windows 7) have a lot of scheduled tasks running now and then and only few people are aware of them.

Comment: To answer some of the comments, here the CMOS clock battery is not at fault as the problem occurs on all our new PCs.

Comment: - I've also disabled the time synchronisation task in the task scheduler.
- I stopped w32time and even disabled it
-I also disabled "Hyper-V Time Synchronisation Service"
Nothing helps, Windows changes the time by one minute every ten days or so. 
When the time changes, my software receives the message wm_timechange, which allows me to record the information, that's how I detect time changes.